# FragmentTransaction adding fragment to top of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a LinearLayout to which I'm adding Fragments dynamically. I use FragmentTransaction.add(), which adds the Fragments to the bottom of the LinearLayout. Is it possible to add some of them to the top?

Comment: If you need to add fragments in the top of your LinearLayout you can simply put a FrameLayout above the LinearLayout and add the fragment into it.

Comment: And if I wanna add more fragments above them?

Comment: FragmentTransaction.replace() can replace the content of the framelayout with another fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a FrameLayout programmatically by using `public void addView (View child, int index)` with the index set to 0. After that you could add your fragment to that layout via a FragmentTransaction.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the FrameLayout with the Fragment instead of adding it inside?

Comment: Unfortunately not because the fragment needs a container view.